# Unable to locate VBScript.Encrypt

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2019, asp-classic

I'm in the process of trying to migrate a legacy ASP application from Windows Server 2008 R2 to a Windows Server 2022 box.

Currently, I'm having trouble with the application being encoded by the creator using `VBScript.Encrypt` as the language for the ASP files.

Eg:
`<%@ LANGUAGE = VBScript.Encrypt %>`

I can't seem to find the component that I need to install online and am having trouble finding it on the system using `grep` from cygwin.

Any thoughts on where the files might be that I need to copy over to the new server?

Edit:
I should not we're not on good terms with the company that produces this application because they're refusing to do the clean install for us. Trying to do this migration without headaches caused by getting Legal involved.

Comment: `we're not on good terms with the company that produces this application` even if you were, it's still an off topic subject. If it isn't the built-in encryption found in VBE files the encryption algorithm could be anything.

Comment: Duplicate question on Stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77889647/missing-vbscript-encrypt-on-windows-server-2019